# Dojo tabcontainer in titlepane does not work in version > 1.6

Tags: javascript, dojo

Placing a tab container on titlepane looks weird in any browser but if I use the dojo v1.6 it appears perfectly. Am I doing something wrong here while porting code to 1.8.4 Or something broken in later versions?

Please change the dojo version in this code and see the difference.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
  <html>  
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title> 
    </title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/**1.6**/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">    
    <style type="text/css"> 
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map{
        padding:0;
      }
    </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var djConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true
      };
    </script> 

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      dojo.require("dijit.dijit"); // optimize: load dijit layer
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("dijit.TitlePane");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
      //require(["dojo/dnd/move", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/TitlePane", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dojox/layout/ExpandoPane", "dojo/domReady!"]);
    </script> 

  </head> 

  <body class="claro"> 
    <div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;">
        <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" style="width:500px;height:500px; border:1px solid #000;padding:0;">
       <div style="position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px; left:30px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">

       <div id="titlepane" dojoType="dijit.TitlePane" title="Show Tabs" closable="false"  open="false">
              <div id="tabContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                <div id="one" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab 1" selected="true">
                  Tab 1 content
                </div>
                <div id="two" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab 2">
                  Tab 2 content
                </div>
                <div id="three" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab 3">
                  Tab 3 content
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.  First, the code has TitlePane inside of a BorderContainer, but [TitlePane is not designed to reside inside of layout widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/TitlePane.html#introduction):

> It extends ContentPane but since it isn’t used inside other layout widgets

Second, as written, the TabContainer inside the title pane needs an absolute height, not relative.  You can get away with a relative height for TabContainers inside of BorderContainers (or other layout widgets), because BorderContainer calculates the absolute height for you.  Since TitlePane does not provide that calculation, you must specify an absolute height...

or, you can tell TabContainer not to do its own layout with "doLayout=false":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body class='claro'>
        <div data-dojo-id='titlePane' data-dojo-type='dijit/TitlePane' data-dojo-props='region:"trailing"'>
            <div data-dojo-id='tabContainer' data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/TabContainer' data-dojo-props='doLayout:false'>
                <div data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/ContentPane' data-dojo-props='title:"Tab 1"'>Hi!</div>
                <div data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/ContentPane' data-dojo-props='title:"Tab 2"'>There!</div>
            <div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        require(['dojo/ready', 'dojo/parser'], function (ready, Parser) {
            ready(function () {
                Parser.parse().then(function () {
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can replace the data-dojo-props on the TabContainer with style='height:100px;' and get a similar effect.  The only difference is that doLayout false uses the auto height from the contained content, while height:100px gives you a static height.

Comment: Excellent. That works. Is there a document for understanding the layout widgets and sizing the child widgets and do's and don'ts of placing widgets? Thanks.

Comment: @RamC: I think the [layout with Dijit](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dijit_layout/) article is the best user reference.  Offhand, I do not know of any reference on the implementation details. General rule: if it's in (dijit|dojox)/layout/ they will work together.  Otherwise, they are standalone.

Comment: It boggles my mind that Dojo widgets re-implement layout mechanisms and content metrics calculation that clearly should be left to the browser. I've used Dojo professionally for a few years and was one of the reasons I quit my job because I can't stand it - it's layers of rubbish and unnecessary complexity all the way down to the core. I wasted many hours of company time on an issue that was eventually fixed with doLayout: false